# Headers For 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 or Location of Kali 4.13 Installer

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I installed the newest available image from [here](https://www.kali.org/downloads/3/) which was Kali 64 bit v2017.2.

However, using the command `apt-get install headers-linux-$(uname -r)` returns the message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package headers-linux-4.12.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package  by glob 'headers-linux-4.12.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package  by regex 'headers-linux-4.12.0-kali1-amd64'
```

When I check [the pool](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/), it looks like all of the headers are marked as 4.13.0.

Two headed question then: Where do I get the headers for `headers-linux-4.12.0-kali1-amd64`, or where do I find the ISO image file for Kali 4.13.x?

Comment: **sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On kali linux [rolling release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_distribution) the package will be continuously updated , the old package will be removed and replaced by the newest version. on your system you have an old kernel image `linux-image-4.12.0-kali1-amd64` , it is no longer available on the kali linux repository , Also its `linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-amd64` will be removed too.

After the system update (`apt update`) you can check the available `linux-image` and `linux-headers` through:

```
apt-cache search linux-image
apt-cache serach linux-headers
```

based on the `apt-cache` output you can install a specific `linux-image` and `linux-headers` package .

the must important part do not use the `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` , the `uname -r` it will point to `4.12.0-kali1-amd64` headers package which it is no longer available **it will work after installing a new** `linux-image` **and booting the new kernel**.

installing the linux-image and the linux-headers without rebooting , the `linux-headers` package will be useful after the system reboot.

```
apt install linux-image-4.12.0-kali2-amd64
apt install linux-headers-4.12.0-kali2-amd64
```

Or , install the `linux-image` :

```
apt install linux-image-4.12.0-kali2-amd64
```

Reboot your system then install the `linux-headers`:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

now the `uname -r` should point to the `4.12.0-kali2-amd64` kernel headers version.

The easy way is to upgarade entirely your system followig those steps:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

then install the `linux-headers`:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt autoremove
```

The `uname -a` will display:

```
 4.13.0-kali1-amd64
```

On kali-linux rolling the `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain only the following line ([kali docs](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: If you are doing a `apt dist-upgrade` anyway, do you really need the `apt upgrade` first?

Comment: @GAD3R This was amazingly helpful. I hadn't realized there was a difference between the main images and the rolling version. For future readers, I'd advise installing rolling as a first step using the process outlined in "Want an Updated or Custom Kali Image?" on https://www.kali.org/downloads/

Comment: @bu5hman It is not necessary , but it is important if you have the  `apt-listbugs`installed on your system.

Comment: @GAD3R Fair enough,  though it seems mildly inconsistent to worry too much about anything but the severest bugs when the repository is Kali rolling......

Comment: After many googling and trying wrong solutions for 3 hours, this was from far the best answer to the same question from me. Many Thx